# Expose response header Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, response-headers

Getting response headers and I want to expose one of the header from it. For eg, x-cloud-trace-context this header should visible in the browser response body.

I tried with exposedHeaders using CORS but still not getting it on the browser and this leads to preflight mode.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You get the response headers working with its own methods. Response itself has various methods to add/log/.. to do some actions on them. check the `NodeJS` `documentation` to figure it out